# How to use multiple slot transclution in angular 1.5 component, or what to use instead?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm building a panel component in angular 1.5 and want to transclude some markup into this template (simplified):

```
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>{{ $ctrl.title }}</h1>

        <div ng-transclude="menu"></div>
        <div ng-transclude="form" ng-if="$ctrl.formExpanded"></div>
        <div ng-transclude="content"></div>
    </div>
```

and then something like this in the component:

```
    export const panelComponentOptions: angular.IComponentOptions = {
        transclude: {
          'menu': '?panelMenu',
          'form': '?panelForm',
          'content': '?panelContent',
        },
        templateUrl: "panel.html",
        controller: PanelController,
        bindings: {
            title: "@?"
        }
    }
```

But the transclude property of the angular.IComponentOptions is of type boolean, so this won't work.

Som my question is why can't you use multislot transclusion in a component, when you can do it with a directive, and what would you recommend me to do instead?

Do I really need to make separate components of the menu and form? Like this:

```
<panel>
    <panel-menu></panel-menu>
    <panel-form></panel-form>
    <div>
        My content
    </div>
</panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709062/angular-1-5-component-vs-old-directive-where-is-a-link-function) kind of sums up the reasons why you'd probably want to use a directive here instead of a component anyhow. You can certainly make sub-components for your `panel`, but the Angular `component` just doesn't have the advanced options a `directive` has. (See also: [Angular component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component))