# Angular Directive to component angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I have this directive, that i would like to make a component

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('year', function () {
    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.setYear = function (val) {
            $scope.selectedyear = val;
        }
    }];
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: "views/year.html"
    };
});
```

This is what I got so far:

```
 angular.module('app') 
.component('year', {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: "views/year.html"
    });
```

I am not sure how to move my `var controller` into `.component`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you should do convert your directive to component

- There is **no restrict** property for component as it is restricted to elements only.
- For controller you could just set as you did at directive declaration but **outside** of it.
- Controllers for components use **controllerAs** syntax as default so get rid of **$scope**

So your component should look like this...

```
angular.module('app') 
    .component('year', {
        controller: ComponentController,
        templateUrl: "views/year.html"
    });

function ComponentController(){
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.setYear = function (val) {
       $ctrl.selectedyear = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. This kinda works, but I think something else is broke now. Because I have my Year button, but my dropdown selection is not displaying anymore.

Comment: because components are using controllerAs syntax and default alias is $ctrl. you should update your component html with it too. As an example with $scope ng-click="clickBtn()" with controllerAs ng-click="$ctrl.clickBtn()"

Answer (score 0):

Your component should look like this:

```
function YearController() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.setYear = function (val) {
    $ctrl.selectedyear = val;
  }
}

angular.module('app').component('year', {
  templateUrl: 'views/year.html',
  controller: YearController
});
```

For more details, please read the following Stack Overflow question for more deatils:
[Angular 1.5 component vs. old directive - where is a link function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709062/angular-1-5-component-vs-old-directive-where-is-a-link-function)
and the official documentation: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Also, please note that components are restricted to elements only by default.